# How to groupby and plot a 2 columns dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset with two columns: 'Species' and observation 'Year'. I've already subset the data, so that in the below dataset it only contain one species"blue whale":

```
Species  Year
1      Blue Whale  1920
2      Blue Whale  1920
3      Blue Whale  1920
5      Blue Whale  1920
6      Blue Whale  1920
7      Blue Whale  1920
16     Blue Whale  1920
17     Blue Whale  1922
18     Blue Whale  1922
19     Blue Whale  1922
20     Blue Whale  1922
21     Blue Whale  1922
22     Blue Whale  1922
23     Blue Whale  1922
24     Blue Whale  1922
25     Blue Whale  1922
26     Blue Whale  1922
28     Blue Whale  1924
29     Blue Whale  1924
30     Blue Whale  1924
```

In this case, how do I plot year as x-axis and y as the count of blue whale observation in that year?

Comment: What kind of graph do you need? `bar`?

Comment: I used your code and altered to line. Many thankss!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `count`:

```
df.groupby('Year').count().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This one sorted the x lab!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
df['Year'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: How can I sort the x lab according to time?

Comment: If df is already sorted `df['Year'].value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar()`

Comment: If not, `df['Year'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()`